# AWS EKS 1.17. PVC - "waiting for first consumer to be created before binding"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs, kubernetes-pvc

PVC is in a pending state due to the error :

```
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  13s (x3 over 34s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

As a result the pods don't come up. (waiting for pv...) I'm using the aws-ebs storage class.

```
ubuntu@ip$ k get sc
NAME            PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
cloud-storage   ebs.csi.aws.com         Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   true                   31d
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  36d
```

I see that aws-ebs provisioner failure is due to the missing `--cloud-provider=aws` and `--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud_config` arguments on `apiserver` and `controller-manager` Pods but in this case the control plane is managed by AWS. Has anyone come across a similar issue on EKS ?

Comment: The above messages means that no pod is using that PVC. What error do you get in the Pod? and what storageclass does the PVC have?

Comment: The pod does not get created; the pvc uses the cloud-storage(ebs.csi.aws.com) sc.